# Where in the real world we use bit manipulation?

Tags: bit-manipulation, bit

In what what real world applications is bit manipulation used?

Any famous algorithm which uses bit manipulation?

Comment: Bit manipulation is often used on microcontrollers.

Comment: See The Art of Computer Programming volume 4A, chapter Bitwise tricks and techniques, for a whole bunch of especially interesting application. But there are plenty of boring applications as well, and also interesting applications that aren't in there. I believe Fenwick trees aren't in there.

Comment: Setting bits for GPI/O pins is a pretty forward example. Sometimes several i/o-pins are combined in word/byte sized ports. To change the state (as in logical Hi/Low) of a single i/o-pin you need to manipulate the corresponding bits.

Comment: google for "bitwise operator applications" you'll immediately find tons of answers

Answer (score 2):

One interesting example is the Fast inverse square root.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root